# How to get only part of Powershell output for Azure key vault?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I have this PS script and I'm trying to get user access information for all Key vaults in an Azure subscription.

So what I'm getting now is all the Key vault information; name, location, ids, different settings, network rules, and then access policies for each user that has some access. Is there a way to strip this output to only get the vault name and access policies?

```
    $resourceGroup = $_ 
    #Gets the key vaults for this resource group
    $keyVaults =  Get-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

    If ($keyVaults) {
        Write-Host 'Resource Group : ' $resourceGroup
         write-host "`n"
        # Goes through the key vaults for this resource group and shows us the information for each
        Foreach ($keyVault in $keyVaults) {
            Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVault.VaultName
            write-host "`n"
        }    
    } 
 }
```

Comment: `Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVault.VaultName | Select VaultName,AccessPolicies` will return the Access Policies' tenant IDs. `Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVault.VaultName | Select VaultName,AccessPoliciesText` will return the contents of each access policy. You may need to pipe that to `Format-List` to display it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1) (alias Select) to narrow down your object's returned properties. Property `AccessPolicies` returns the `Tenant ID` value associated with each access policy. Property `AccessPoliciesText` returns the text of the policies.

```
Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVault.VaultName | Select VaultName,AccessPolicies
Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVault.VaultName | Select VaultName,AccessPoliciesText
```

Note that since you are selecting only two properties, the default formatted output will be table view. The `AccessPoliciesText` will likely be truncated in table view. You can (for display purposes only) use list format to ***display*** all the contents:

```
Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $keyVault.VaultName |
    Select VaultName,AccessPoliciesText | Format-List
```

Note that ***if you plan to store your output into a variable to process later, do not use `Format-List` until you need to display its value at the console.***